# Is POJO anti Object Orientation (OO)?

Tags: java, oop, object, pojo

In most definitions, POJO (Plain Old Java Object) is object with properties along with just getters/setters. Some people name these DTO. So essentially they are what i like to call them 'Data classes'. Whatever the name is i know there are these kind of objects where it just have getters/setters. And these are commonly used within developing multi-layered MVC web applications - where these objects would be passed through the different layers.

Maybe my question is a bit towards opinionated - but is this pure OOP or not?
I'm determined to find out the answer to this i.e. what's right and what's wrong?

...Because, i have been brought up learning that OOP is all about modelling real-life scenarios/situations into objects through interaction. With objects themselves encapsulate data and behaviour which acts on this data. 
- an object with just getters/setters doesn't fit into this definition in my opinion.

Also, data classes are bad (code smell)  - that's what i've been taught in university.

Comment: So instead of a data class, what would you rather use?  A map?

Comment: Erm, depends on the problem i guess. But a map would be totally acceptable i think. No?

Comment: Use an object to represent intent and encapsulate information.

Comment: No, data objects with concrete types are _definitely_ more OO than maps everywhere.

Comment: Look at the history of Java EE to better understand the significance of the term POJO. In earlier versions of J2EE, you needed an interface and three classes per bean, each implementing a specific platform interface! POJOs are about simplifying all that extraneous boilerplate code.  Also, note that many [behavioral design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) specifically decouple behavior from the data: eg you don't want every data object knowing both XML and JSON and other data formats.

Comment: @ControlAltDel that's because there are so much conflicting information on the internet it's unbelievable.

Comment: @MattBall thanks. A lot of developers in my company do that - using Maps to pass data around

Comment: As answered by Makoto, you should change question title to Java Beans instead of POJO, I think, Java Beans convention clashes with OOPs in the sense that state info is not passed to children ( as those are mandatory marked to be private ) , plus Java beans convention introduces lots of duplicate code ( because same fields declaration get repeated in children ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as pure OOP.  How people worked with OO changed over the years.

I'm more inclined to add behaviour to my types (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). If you treat a type as a datacontainer (POJO) you'll need to put that behaviour somewhere.  Usually something called xxxService.  That's an extra level of indirection just to do something which may be the core business of that "POJO".

After writing some more code you may end up with having the need for this function somewhere else.  Now you'd need to extract this to some helper which you can share.  Which means you'll have like 2 services calling the same method acting upon your POJO.  Another level of indirection added.

But that's one way of doing it.  I've worked on quite a few projects and a lot of developers feel more comfortable with the setter/getter thing.  If you have a team which feels more comfortable with setters/getters, why not.
It won't kill the project but you'll have to see it every day ;)

Answer (score 4):

POJO and XXService is bad idea! Any action(method) belong to an Object.

OK, just look a sample, it's people's simple action:

```
Class People {
    string name;
}

Class PeopleService{
   public void pee(People people){
      System.out.print(people.name + " relax...");
   }   
}
```

aha, now we need extend it..., we know some difference between man and woman

```
class Man extends People{}

class Woman extends People{}
```

if only one service, you should write:

```
Class PeopleService {
   public void pee(People people){
      if(people instanceof Man)//if ... and if ...
          System.out.println("stand up");
      if(people instanceof Woman)
          System.out.println("sit down");
      System.out.print(people.name + " relax...");
   }  
}
```

if you extends your service:

```
Class ManService extends PeopleService {
    @Override
    public void pee(People people){
      if(people instanceof Man)
          System.out.println("stand up");
      super.pee();
   }
}

Class WomanService extends PeopleService {
    @Override
    public void pee(People people){
      if(people instanceof woman) //you must check it
          System.out.println("sit down");
      super.pee();
   }
}

//maybe wrong when anyone call these service
...
People p = new Woman();
...
manService.pee(p);//you can't stop it!
```

than we can write a serviceFactory..., so crazy!
but OOP code, People is domain object and it's perfect!

```
Class People {

   String name;

   public void pee(){
      System.out.print(name + " relax...");
   } 
}

Class Man extends People {
   @Override 
   public void pee() {
      System.out.println("stand up");
      super.pee();
   }
}

Class Woman extends People {
   @Override 
   public void pee() {
      System.out.println("sit down");
      super.pee();
   }
}

//we call it now, don't care about details 
...
People p1 = new Man();
People p2 = new Woman();
p1.pee();
p2.pee();
```

thinking of OOP basicly! Most of programer forgot it!

Comment: In OOPs , `string name;` is a state information & that state information should go to children - `Man` as well as `Woman` classes but in typical POJO, this field will be marked as `private` with `public` getter & setters & thats where it clashes with OOPs plus lots of duplicate code.

Comment: A class with "extends" is not a POJO! See Wikipedia definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object#Definition

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this question is a year old. However I feel the jist of POJO's has not been addressed by the other answers.

To answer your question: "Is POJO anti Object Orientation (OO)?".

No and yes.

**Simple anwser explanation**

No, because OO is about modeling concepts you need. A POJO does exactly that. It bundles bits of information into an Object.

Yes, because there are some principles used in OO which a POJO violates. Such as the `tell don't ask`-principle.

**Detailed answer explanation**

POJO's are nothing but data-containers. You don't tell a POJO to do anything. It is just a representation of a bit of information. As such, you ask it for its current state. Which mean you are violating `tell dont ask`.

This however is unavoidable at one point. Just like functional programming languages introduce IO definitions to specify the function is not "pure". You will have to go outside your neat little OO-bubble program to ask things to.. urhg.. the outside..

*Wrapping your POJO's*

This is why I wrap POJO's in models (naming depends on what you prefer, I call them models). You can do this with extension (like Klaus does in his answer) or composition (which I prefer). Which ever tickles your fancy.

The POJO defines a real-life/abstract data-source (you don't always model real-life stuff).

*Implementing tell don't ask*

This is then passed to a DataModel which is the responsible for manipulating the POJO.

It does this by being "told" to manipulate the POJO. The reason I do this is because at times POJO's contain type information. 
As a result directly manipulating the POJO will often result in some Class having to check the typing of the POJO.

Often doing something like:

```
if(POJO.type == "something"){
   this.doSmthWithPOJO();
}
```

Now you might end up with a whole lot of POJO's with a different type. In that case you might end up with something like this:

```
if(POJO.type == "something"){
       this.doSomethingWithPOJO(POJO);
} 
else if (POJO.type == "something else")
{
    this.doSomethingElseWithPOJO(POJO);
}
else if( POJO.type == "something else entirely")
{
    this.doSomethingElseEntirelyWithPOJO(POJO);
}
else{
   this.print("This is starting to get ugly...");
}
```

You're doing this because the type information in your POJO means you have to do something a tiny bit different. Having the POJO inside a DataModel with functions you can call allows you to do something much cleaner. While moving responsiblity for manipulation or typechecking outside your class.

```
POJOTypeDataModel model = new POJOTypeDataModel(POJO);
```

Then the If-elseif-else-statement above because much simpler.

```
model.doSomething();
```

As I mentioned above you will have to ask about the "POJO.type" at one point. 
I do this when I first need the data-source. The data-source call returns the POJO(s). You check its type and return a DataModel instead of the POJO.

It's important to emphasize you only have to check the POJO's type once! Which is at the moment you retrieve/create the POJO and wrap it.

If the POJO isn't wrapped or specifically typed you will have to ask the POJO for its type a lot more. This clutters the original intend of the class which is using the POJO.
It also gets rid of a whole lot of if-statements.

Furthermore you're also encouraging working with abstractions and not specific types.

**In short**

Doing the above helps you to:

1. Keep the outside outside. As a POJO is often a data-source.
2. Adhere to `tell don't ask` as much as possible.
3. Encourage use abstractions instead of concrete types (can't get more concrete than a POJO).
4. Write cleaner (you don't type-check everywhere) and easier to understand code (people are notoriously bad at understanding large chunks of procedural code).
5. Ultimately the wrapping helps you to avoid changes to your code . As you're probably type-checking the POJO everywhere in your code (see the if example). Now you simple call a function on the DataModel and it knows what to do.

**Back to the simple answer**

You can't avoid having to ask a POJO for information. Yet it is perfect for modeling a data-source.

So wrapping it and using abstractions to call a DataModel limits the violation of some core OO-principles and it makes for neater code.

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting POJO mixed up with Beans a little bit, and there's a significant difference.

- A bean is a class that has strong conventions about the naming of its getters/setters (`get___` for any non-boolean, and `is___` for a boolean).  A POJO does not.
- A bean has a no-arg constructor in it, and it may implement `Serializable`.  A POJO might not do either.
- A bean's fields must be private.  A POJO's fields may not be.

Now, to the question: if done well, a POJO can properly encapsulate data and behave in an OO manner.  You would be operating on a specific object instead of exposing its internals for you to have to fiddle with (as in, for instance, if you only had a map to work with; it'd be *marginally* better if you encapsulated that map in an object).

The times when it wouldn't really behave in an OO manner is when the POJO takes on more responsibilities than it should have.

Answer (score 1):

When you say data classes, I am assuming you are talking similar structures to `struct` in C and C++ where it contains only data. Personally I do not think data classes are bad, neither is it a code smell.

Data classes allows you to group several attributes which belongs to the same entity together. For example:

```
class Monster{
    String name;
    int hp;
    int damage;
}
```

With the above you can pass the entire monster object around in the arguments:

```
public void attack(Monster m){
    //Attack monster
}
```

instead of:

```
public void attack (String name, int hp, int damage){
    //Attack monster
}
```

If it is bad, why would people occasionally be using `struct` instead of classes in C++?

Comment: Not a C++ developer myself, I'm a Java developer myself. But i take your comments on board. There are definitely welcomed. Very good points for thought.

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper Sure. Further more when we talk about OO, it reminds us things like encapsulation, inheritance & polymorphism. Even if it is a class with only getters and setters, it is still obeying the above 3 properties and it still fits into the OOP concept.